# Tesseract OCR failure C#

Tags: c#, ocr, tesseract

Here is the error in the console :

```
Error opening data file /./tesssdata/eng.traineddatta
Please make sure the TESSDATA_PREFIX enviroment variable is set to the parent directory of your "t2ssdata" directory
Failed loading language 'eng'
Tesseract couldn't load any languages!
```

The problem is I have esablished the enviroment variable on the system to the proper tessdata location where the eng.traineddatta file is. Which exists as part of this project.

From what i saw the tessdata folder from the .tar.gz file needed to be extracted to the project in the debug directory of the build. which is what I did.

After putting in the enviroment variable i restarted my computer and still getting the same issue.

What am i missing?

Comment: Can we see your code please?  I'm particularly interested in where `t2ssdata` is coming from

Comment: Don't restart your computer after setting the environment variable. Does it work?

Comment: the t2ssdata was a typo that is my bad, error was just setting the incorrect directory i was setting it to the tessdata directory not the parent of that directory. and i did need to restart my computer to reset the enviroment variable.